# Scala case class constructor error when used as POJO strategy in Ignite persistence

Tags: scala, ignite, pojo

I have a case class in Scala as so:

```
class StateCache(greeting: String, first_name: String, last_name: String)
```

I am using Spark + Ignite to have a write through cache that persists to Cassandra. When setting the persistence-settings.xml file to:

```
<persistence keyspace="testing_ignite" table="people_test">
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.Long" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="index"/>
    <valuePersistence class="StateCache" strategy="POJO"/>
</persistence>
```

I receive the following error:
`Java class 'StateCache' couldn't be used as POJO cause it doesn't have no arguments constructor`. I have added in an empty constructor but it does not resolve the error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/v2.0/docs/base-concepts) for POJO (highlighting is mine):

> Stores each field of an object as a column having corresponding type in Cassandra table. Provides ability to utilize Cassandra secondary indexes for object fields. Could be used ***only for POJO objects following Java Beans convention*** and having their fields of simple java type which could be directly mapped to corresponding Cassandra types.

Your class `StateCache` does not follow Java Beans spec. To fix this you need:

- declare all the fields as `var` (instead of `val`)
- use the [`@BeanProperty` annotation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/beans/BeanProperty.html) on them
- declare an empty constructor

The code would go like this:

```
class StateCache(@BeanProperty var greeting: String, 
                 @BeanProperty var first_name: String, 
                 @BeanProperty var last_name: String) {
    def this() {
        this(null,null,null);
    }
}
```

This is not an idiomatic Scala but this is what you need to interact with the world that uses Java conventions.